How can I sync the SQL schema of my database across all my environments
I have a relational database that uses SQL. I am implementing a new feature that requires adding a new column.
This means that I have to go about to all instances of my DB across all my environments and add the column.
What can I do to make this process easier?

Which RDBMS are you using? You've tagged 3! all of which have completely different ways of syncing schemas... please tag only the one you ae using. And yes there are tools that do that... in fact a simple search for find them for you. What did you find when you researched?

The tools like Liquibase, Flyway allow to describe the database schema and changes in a text-based format, which can be version-controlled, reviewed, and applied consistently across all instances of the database.
Let's go with Flyway Database Migration Tool :
How it works is you create SQL migration files that describe your changes (ex : adding a column). Flyway keeps track of which migrations have already been applied to the database and applies any new migrations when the server starts.
Step 1 : Download Flyway from the official website
Step 2 : Create Migration File
Place your migration files in the db/migration directory. Name your files with a version prefix, ex : V1__Add_new_column.sql
-- V1__Add_new_column.sql
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN new_column VARCHAR(255);

Step 3 : Configure Flyway. Create a flyway.conf file with your database connection details.
properties :
flyway.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdatabase
flyway.user=youruser
flyway.password=yourpassword

Step 4 : Apply migrations
You can run Flyway from the command line or integrate it into your build process.
Ex :
flyway migrate

Note : You can go with 'Liquibase' if you want flexibility in how you define your changes (XML, YAML, JSON, SQL) and need features like rollback, change history etc.

ChatGPT answers are banned
